# Catching .Net Standard exception in framework

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard

I have a .net standard library that throws an exception defined in netstandard2.0 (System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException). I have a test assembly compiled against 4.7.2 framework that calls the standard library, and wants to catch the exception. Everything compiles fine. At runtime, the catch is not triggering because the ConfigurationErrorsException it linked to is from 4.7.2 instead of standard. Note the error I get from a unit test.

How can I tell my framework code to catch a standard exception? Note I do not want to/can't make the test assembly into net standard also.

> Message: Test method RequiredFieldNotSet threw exception 
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException, but exception System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException was expected. Exception message: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Parameter 'AnInt' is required but was not set!

```
        try
        {
            SampleSettingsClass target = new SampleSettingsClass(settingsProvider);
        }
        catch (System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException)
        {
            failed = true;
        }
```

If I use catch(Exception) instead, the exception is caught. The fully qualified types of the expected framework exception and the thrown net standard exception are different.

```
//framework 
 typeof(System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException).AssemblyQualifiedName
"System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"

//net standard 
e.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName
"System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51"
```

Comment: I'm confused, because I don't see System.Configuration in the [list of .NET Standard APIs](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/tree/master/src/netstandard/ref).  It's not listed in the [.NET API Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netstandard-2.0&term=System.Configuration) for .NET Standard 2.0 either.

Comment: @Powerlord Probably you want this https://source.dot.net/#System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/System/Configuration/ConfigurationErrorsException.cs,e66c32f670e40381

Comment: @PranavSingh That's from the .NET Core source, not .NET Standard.

Comment: Why does it compile then?

Comment: the disassembly points to system.configuration.configurationmanager\4.5.0\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll

Comment: The System.Configuration classes are not part of .NETStandard, you got it by adding a Nuget package.  So in effect your assembly is not .NETStandard compliant anymore.  Yes, ugly problem.  You'll have to catch this exception before it leaks out to your .NETFramework code.

Comment: but I added a net standard assembly...

Comment: shouldn't the exception be converted to the framework version, so that it's usable in framework? Isn't that the point of standard?

Comment: Yes, the point of .NETStandard classes is that they get [TypeForwardedTo] an equivalent .NETFramework or .NETCore class at runtime.  But since System.Configuration classes are **not** covered by .NETStandard those attributes are missing.  That isn't normally much of a problem since you'd only use the Nuget package classes in your own assembly.  But exceptions are the gritty problem, they can teleport across assemblies.  Not much terribly wrong about catching Exception btw, it is ultimately a "it did not work" exception that you can only "handle" by ignoring it.  Questionable tactic.

Comment: So nuget packages that are compiled to net standard are still missing these attributes to allow type forwarding? It's not mandatory for all net standard assemblies?

Comment: Isn't this problem much bigger as it can affect any type turned from standard back to framework? Does that mean all nuget standard libraries are not actually usable in framework?

Comment: In other words, `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` is supposed to be used by a .NET Core application that only runs on Windows, because it is part of the so called Windows Compatibility Pack for .NET Core. Like you discovered, your library is used by a .NET Framework application, then the application can end up this way. Please remove any Windows dependent code from such a .NET Standard library, as such code should live in a .NET Framework project instead.

Comment: @LexLi is that comment to me? I don't own the system.configuration.configurationManager library, and I don't know if it has windows dependent code. This seems more an issue of what it means to compile against standard, and how that's different than being in the standard.

Answer (score 0):

As Hans says in the comment, if my framework app links to the standard System.Configuration assembly instead of the framework version, then I can catch this exception. It's just that the magic retyping I expected does not apply to 3rd party libraries (sadly).